# Perform different actions in top 3 values in Dictionary?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I have a sorted dictionary with certain number of entries:

```
dict = {B:3, A:2, C:2, D:1, E:0, F:0...}
```

After filtering the dictionary to get only the entries with top 3 largest values:

```
result = Object.fromEntries(Object
    .entries(dict)
    .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)                         
    .filter((s => ([, v]) => s.add(v).size <= 3)(new Set))
);
```

The current dictionary is

```
{"B": 3, "A": 2, "C": 2, "D": 1}
```

So I am trying to add `4` to the largest values,`2` to the second largest values and `1` to the third largest values, what are the ways to do this?

The expected output: `{"B": 7, "A": 4, "C": 4, "D": 2}`

One of the ways I can think of is:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(result)) {
     // if result[key] largest
            //plus 4
     // if result[key] second largest
            //plus 2
     // else
            //plus 1 
}
```

Thanks for reading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) as:

```js
const dict = { B: 3, A: 2, C: 2, D: 1, E: 0, F: 0 };
const valuesToAdd = [4, 2, 1];
const result = Object.fromEntries([
    ...Object.entries(dict)
      .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)
      .filter( ( (s) => ([, v]) => s.add(v).size <= 3 )(new Set()) )
      .reduce((map, arr) => {
        const [k, v] = arr;
        map.has(v) ? map.get(v).push(arr) : map.set(v, [arr]);
        return map;
      }, new Map())
      .values(),
  ].flatMap((arr, i) => arr.map(([k, v]) => [k, v + valuesToAdd[i]]))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Um I meant how to add 4,2,1 to the dictionary entries with top 3 largest values.. So in my case B has the largest value so add 4, A and C has the second largest value so add 2, D has the third largest value so add 1. The expected output would be {"B": 7, "A": 4, "C": 4, "D": 2}...

Comment: @PeanutJams Edited code. Have a look